# ¿Cómo instalar la gema mysql2 en ruby?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Estoy tratando de instalar la gema mysql2 en lubuntu pero no lo consigo, en windows no encontré problema alguno pero prefiero trabajar con linux, espero que alguien me ayude a solucionar este problema tan molesto.

Siempre obtengo lo siguiente:

```
sudo gem install mysql2


Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.1/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20180701-12889-gixoce.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

> Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.1 for inspection.
>       Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/mysql2-0.5.1/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente falten las herramientas para compilar la extensión

```
sudo apt-get install gcc ruby-dev rubygems make
```

ver https://stackoverflow.com/a/27655813/1423096

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener instaladas las librerías de desarrollo de mysql. Para Ubuntu/Debian deberías probar con:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Y en caso que hayas instalado ruby desde los sources de Ubuntu y no desde un gestor de versiones (rvm, rbenv, asdf), también deberías instalar:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby
```